# How to monitor disk usage of persistent volumes of all storageclasses using Prometheus?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, metrics, kubernetes-pvc, persistent-volume-claims

I am using [Kubernetes Persistent Volumes](https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/13646) dashboard on Grafana to view the disk usage for my PVCs. This dashboard makes use of `kubelet_volume_stats_used_bytes` metric to fetch the data for the PVCs and I am able to visualize it as well.

But, it does not display the PVCs which use EFS as storageclass.
I found some stackoverflow answers and comments regarding the same, but none of them included a solution.

[How to monitor kubernetes persistence volume claim i.e disk usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58552039/how-to-monitor-kubernetes-persistence-volume-claim-i-e-disk-usage?rq=1#comment103545426_58559416)

[How to monitor disk usage of kubernetes persistent volumes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44718268/how-to-monitor-disk-usage-of-kubernetes-persistent-volumes?noredirect=1&lq=1)

So my question is how do get usage metrics for EFS PVCs?
Or to make it more generic - how to scrape PVC metrics for all storageclasses?

Comment: Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55899797/how-to-monitor-disk-usage-of-persistent-volumes) to monitor disk usage of persistent volumes of all storageclasses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EFS PVCs don't have any size limits. Thats why this traditional method doesn't work while checking their disk usage.
Instead, I was able to use a sidecar-logging mechanism to get this data -

Attach the following sidecar to the pod which is using the PVC `myPvcName`

```yaml
      containers:
      - name: pvc-logging
        image: busybox:latest
        command: [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "--" ]
        args: [ "while true; do du -sh /myPvc ; sleep 5; done;" ]
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /myPvc
          name: myPvc
          readOnly: true
      volumes:
        - name: myPvc
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: myPvcName
```

This sidecar -

- has the `MyPvcName` pvc mounted at the path `/myPvc`
- checks the space used by this pvc every 5 seconds (you can change this interval)

It's logs look like -

```bash
10.3G   /myPvc
10.3G   /myPvc
10.4G   /myPvc
```

These can be parsed using whatever logging stack you use - in my case, it was the elastic stack.

But I haven't yet looked into how I can send these logs into prometheus so I can visualise them on Grafana.