# how to monitor pv - pvc - storageclass

Tags: local-storage, grafana, prometheus-node-exporter, kubernetes-pvc

i have a issue with moritoring pvc
my infra system:

- deploy k8s with kubeadm on premise
- monitoring system: prometheus - grafana.
- k8s scrape config: <kubernetes_sd_config>

  - role: node, endpoints, pods, cadvisor ...
    i see many metrics but do not have somethings like: kubelet_volume_stats_used_bytes or kubelet_volume_stats_capacity_bytes or somethings like that.

I want to monitor: how many pvc, used - percent used , free ...
So someone can give a suggestion, reference links to achive my goal ( change monitoring system, update configmap ...).

I am begginer in k8s, pls help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdViC.png)

i referenced many link:

- [How to monitor disk usage of persistent volumes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55899797/how-to-monitor-disk-usage-of-persistent-volumes)
- https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/7685-kubernetes-persistent-volumes-usage/
- https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter

Version:
clientVersion:
gitVersion: v1.27.3
goVersion: go1.20.5
serverVersion:
gitVersion: v1.26.1
goVersion: go1.19.5